# Как найти элемент по содержанию селектора python?

Tags: python, selenium

```
match1 = "Spirit"
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()=match1]").click()
```

На сайте в селекторе содержится текст "Spirit". Нужно найти этот элемент и нажать.

Comment: `browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//div[text()="{match1}"]').click()`

Comment: или  `browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//div[contains(text(),"{match1}")]').click()`

Comment: Ваш код ищет элемент с текстом "match1".